# Velocity Template foreach loop

Tags: java, html, velocity

I'm trying to get two parameters out of a HashMap of ArrayLists in order to build up an  tag.

My .vm file currently looks like this:

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
    #foreach ($x in $documents)
        <li><a href="${x.get("documentPath")}" target="_blank">${x.get("documentTitle")}</a></li>
    #end
</ul>
```

This is how I'm building the HashMap:

```
final ArrayList<Map<String, String>> documentsList = new ArrayList<>();
if (recallInfo.getDocuments() != null && !recallInfo.getDocuments().isEmpty())
{
    final String contextPath = ServletActionContext.getServletContext().getContextPath();
    for (final SessionDocument document : recallInfo.getDocuments())
    {
        final String documentPath = contextPath + "/content/document/view?id=" + document.getId();
        final String documentTitle = Strings.shorten(document.getTitle(), 60);
        Map<String, String> documents = new HashMap<>();
        documents.put("documentPath", documentPath);
        documents.put("documentTitle", documentTitle);
        documentsList.add(documents);
    }
}
templateContext.put("documents", documentsList);
```

I am wondering whether this is the correct syntax to use as I am not getting any results appear. I've built the URLs manually so I know that they are correct.

Answer (score 0):

You are having list of map value but what you did is just iterating list . You have to do iteration for map also in order to get two values

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">

    #foreach ($document in $documents)
        #foreach ($map in $document.keySet())

            <li><a href="${document.get("documentPath")}" target="_blank">${document.get("documentTitle")}</a></li>
        #end
    #end
</ul>
```